# Responsive Design - Iphone not picking up media query... works in browser

Tags: iphone, mobile, media-queries

working on this site: http://thegoodgood.com/gus_2
responsive queries are working in browser but when i go to iphone it isnt using the queries... 
you can see it here:
 http://www.we-are-gurus.com/tools/responsive-design-tester.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fthegoodgood.com%2Fgus_2%2F&d=320x480&scroll=off#

i have made sure this is included in header:

a little stumped????

this is the query im using: @media screen and (max-width: 540px)  {

( i have scoured the web and tried a bunch of differnet queries to try to target the width but nothing.... )

thanks for any ideas / help!

Comment: If I shrink my pc browser to 320 width it looks the same as on my iPhone.  What are you expecting?

Comment: hello! - im expecting it to use the media queries that i have set up... when i shrink my browsers down it goes it uses the media queries: http://grab.by/j9mW   but on iphone its just the normal styles: http://grab.by/j9n0 ... so im expecting the iphone to use the media queries like i see it in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the site in Safari or Chrome you'll notice the media queries also don't work.  This is because they are more strict about closing brackets than firefox, you don't have closing brackets for your 900px media query or your 740px media query.  Add those 2 brackets and iPhones should change properly.

If you would like to support Internet Explorer you might want to check your site out on that browser also.

Comment: i love you. and i feel a little bit stupid - thanks for your time